# Is it possible to have multiple simultaneous tweens within a LeanTween sequence?

Tags: unity, tweening

I'm trying to create a sequence that controls multiple animating objects (ObjectA and ObjectB). I want it to look like this...

> Step 1: ObjectA moves to center, while rotating.
>
> Step 2: ObjectB moves to center.
>
> Step 3: ObjectA and ObjectB move together simultaneously to left

So my initial instinct was to do it all using a single sequence. However after reviewing all the documentation and examples I can find, I have not found a way to make a sequence in which you are running multiple tweens at a single step. For instance, as far as I can tell, you can't do anything like:

```
LTSeq sequence = LeanTween.Sequence();
//step 1
sequence.append( <Move ObjectA> AND <Rotate ObjectA>);//There is no way to do this?
//step 2
sequence.append( <Move ObjectB>);
//step 3
sequence.append (<Move ObjectA> AND <Move ObjectB>); //No way to do this either?
```

So I also tried making two sequences that would run simultaneously, like so:

```
LTSeq sequenceA = LeanTween.Sequence();
LTSeq sequenceB = LeanTween.Sequence();
//step1
sequenceA.append( <Move ObjectA>);
sequenceB.append( <Rotate ObjectA>); 
//step 2
sequenceA.append( <Move ObjectB>);
sequenceB.append( <Wait> );
//step 3
sequenceA.append( <Move ObjectA>);
sequenceB.append( <Move ObjectB>);
```

But when I do this, Sequences A and B still occur sequentially even though they are separate objects, instead of simultaneously as expected.

Does anyone here know how to make LeanTween perform multiple simultaneous tweens within a sequence? I'm out of ideas.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the `insert` method, this allows you to branch off from the regular sequence and won't delay any future `append` calls.

You can find a usage of this in the GeneralSequencer.cs file inside Examples/Scripts in the LeanTween install. The relevant bit of code...

```
// Jump up
var seq = LeanTween.sequence();

seq.append( LeanTween.moveY( avatar1, avatar1.transform.localPosition.y + 6f, 1f).setEaseOutQuad() );

// Power up star, use insert when you want to branch off from the regular sequence (this does not push back the delay of other subsequent tweens)
seq.insert( LeanTween.alpha(star, 0f, 1f) );
seq.insert( LeanTween.scale( star, Vector3.one * 3f, 1f) );

// Rotate 360
seq.append( LeanTween.rotateAround( avatar1, Vector3.forward, 360f, 0.6f ).setEaseInBack() );
```